# New battery: "The battery's capacity is significantly reduced."

Tags: battery, charging, power

I changed the battery in my old Macbook Air 11" (mid 2013). It all appears to work fine after installation. To recalibrate the power system, I followed the steps outlined by, e.g., [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Battery_Calibration):

1. With the computer turned off, I let the battery charge until the connector went green, and two hours more.
2. I disconnected the power cable, turned on the computer, turned off all power saving measures, and let the battery slowly drain until the computer turned off. I left the computer turned off for 5+ more hours.
3. I reattached the power cable, turned on the computer, and let it fully charge.

Unfortunately, the battery pane still says

> The battery's capacity is significantly reduced. To restore capacity, please check your service options.

[image]

Resetting the SMC didn't make a difference.

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: What does coconut battery tell us about the battery?

Comment: What battery did you change it to?

Comment: I'm not sure that leaving it completely empty for a long period of time is a good idea. Where did you read that method? Also, where did you purchase the battery. I don't think Apple sells parts for that model.

Comment: X_841 I don't understand what you're tryingto say.

Comment: @SolarMike A battery I purchased from Amazon.

Comment: @benwiggy All online tutorials recommend this procedure, e.g., [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Battery_Calibration).

Comment: So, you purchased a non OEM battery from a cheap supplier and expect what sort of quality?

Comment: Agree @SolarMike - I’ll make a proper answer to cover the options. Mac still needs service clearly. The one detail that’s curious is “ the battery pane still says” does that mean it showed that before the repair started, as soon as the repair was done and after the “recalibration” attempt?  DIY repair questions are always tough to balance how much detail to report so OP did a great job here IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Cabling can’t really affect the capacity of a battery, so reworking that won’t help.

You’re left with:

- the battery is working just as it left the retailer
- the battery was damaged during the install
- the battery was damaged during shipment
- the logic board has failed

The os clearly indicates you need service. The service tech that sees your Mac might cover follow on questions like:

- What sort of support and warranty did the vendor provide?
- Did the battery you replaced have the identical capacity and warning?