# How to remove MacBook Pro 'battery's capacity is significantly reduced' warning?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, warranty

**Background**

- 2017 13" Macbook Pro w/ AppleCare
- purchased new in 2017
- had intermittent charging issues - would not see charger and drain rapidly
- could never reproduce for Apple to diagnose
- late 2020 AppleCare was due to expire and original battery failed and was replaced

**Current Issue**

Fast forward to now - had the charging issue return and I get this:

[image]

I should get 1000 cycles from this and now:

[image]

Barely a year out and under 100 cycles and it's dead again.  Tried these:

- Called Apple (surprise - you are SOL)
- SMC / VRAM etc.
- List item
- Battery calibration trick ([New battery: "The battery's capacity is significantly reduced."](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434969/new-battery-the-batterys-capacity-is-significantly-reduced))
- Deleting the power management plists etc.

This is MacOS 12.1 BTW.

I had planned to continue to use this computer for years - it has lots of RAM and I never have issues with it.  When I got the new battery under AppleCare I figured I had a 'new' laptop that would add years to it's life.  Now I have a boat anchor I can't sell.  The battery is part of the entire top case / keyboard (thanks Apple ‍♂️) and the costs is half the value of the unit now.

**Questions**

1. Can you ever guilt Apple to honour a goodwill repair etc?
2. Can you reset this message